# Hibernate: cannot delete parent object in a bidirectionnal association

Tags: hibernate

I have a bi-directional association between two tables **parent** and **child**

```
<class name="child" table="child">
      <id name="id" column="id" />
      <many-to-one name="parent_id" column="parent_id" 
                          class="parent" cascade="save-update"/>
</class>

<class name="parent" table="parent">
     <id name="id" column="id" />
     <set name="children" inverse="true" cascade="delete" >
         <key column="parent_id" />
         <one-to-many class="child" />
     </set>
</class>
```

I'm just getting an `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` when trying to delete the parent.

How can I make hibernate delete for me all children associated to a parent when deleting this parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the children using the delete orphan option on your mapping. This is described [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-transitive). This works because the lifespan of the children is bounded by the lifespan of the parent. Hibernate knows that it should remove the children when it removes the parent and therefore avoids violating the constraint. I.e. it deletes the children and then the parent. Without this you can expect to violate the contraint.

Comment: Could you mark that as the correct answer then please :) Thanks!